# GPO refresh error - Policy Refresh has not completed in the expected time. Exiting

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, active-directory, group-policy

I'm having problem with my GPO changes, that I'd like to force to my terminal server users here's what I've done:

1. I've made some necessary changes in one of the Domain Controllers to disable the GPO which applies to my Terminal Server user OU
2. and then I go to the Terminal Server mstsc /admin console to perform the GPo refresh by using /force parameter, however I got this error instead:

C:\Documents and Settings\Adminisrator>gpupdate /force
Refreshing Policy...

**User Policy Refresh has not completed in the expected time. Exiting...**
User Policy Refresh has completed.

**Computer Policy Refresh has not completed in the expected time. Exiting...**
Computer Policy Refresh has completed.

FYI: 
the target TS is running on Windows Server 2003 Standard R2 SP2 64 bit edition
the GPO object that I changed is the Enable Clipboard Redirection (Computer GPO - Loopback) - so that the user is now able to copy paste as opposed previously disabled.

but then the changes still got no effect yet as I logged in to the terminal server ?

is there any way of how to make it in effect immediately please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Application and System logs for errors after the GPUPDATE fails. This also could be an issue with the computer reaching a DC - you might have AD issues afoot as well.

Let us know...

Comment: hm..unfortunately I couldn't see it in the event viewer ifthere is any error after the GPUPDATE /force failed to execute :-|